# Propriedade Disabled HTML e Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alguém sabe o porque que nao está desabilitando a propriedade (disabled) no jquery.Ou seja, ao clicar no botão.Quero que ao clicar no botão fique(disabled=false)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#b2").click(function(){

       $("input").prop(disabled,false);

           });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>



    <input  disabled="true">

    <button id="b2">botao</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar propriedades ou atributos de um elemento com jQuery, na sintaxe, o nome do *atributo* e o *valor* devem vir entre aspas:

```
$('elemento').prop('atributo', 'valor');
```

No caso de `disabled`, por ser um valor [booleano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booleano), pode ser fora das aspas:

```
$('elemento').prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tens de usar uma *String* para o nome da propriedade.

Muda

```
.prop(disabled, false);
```

para

```
.prop('disabled', false);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $("input").prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input disabled="true">

<button id="b2">botao</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo